# Text box does not recognize integer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I am build calculator on Visual Basic Express Edition 2010.

but when I am run code it error this line

```
TextBox3 = c
```

Error   1   Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'.  C:\Users\INFRA\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb    7   20  WindowsApplication1

Complete code are:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim a, b, c As Integer
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    a = Val(TextBox1)
    b = Val(TextBox2)
    c = a + b
    TextBox3 = c

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: `c.ToString()`, you can't enter integer into text. And also, its `textbox .Text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Text` property of the textbox.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim a, b, c As Integer
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    a = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    b = Val(TextBox2.Text)
    c = a + b
    TextBox3.Text = c.ToString()

End Sub
```